# No internal sound card detected after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 22.04

I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04.  I was able to hear sound from the internal sound card before the upgrade but not after.  However, I was able to hear sound on a bluetooth speaker.
If I open pavucontrol I get "Aucune carte n'est disponible pour la configuration" (no card is available to configure) under configuration. I get something similar with ALSA for instance:

```
> arecord -l
arecord: device_list:274: aucune carte son n'a été trouvée...
#(no sound card found)
```

However, the sound card is detected by the system.

```
> inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: N/A
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-35-lowlatency running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

I noticed that this audio driver may be problematic and one possible remedy was to reinstall ALSA and pulse audio. I ran the following lines:

```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
> sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
> sudo apt-get install alsa-base
> sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
> sudo alsa force-reload
and reboot
```

After this I was still unable to detect the sound card and no longer able to use an external speaker.  Any ideas?